# Static page on EC2 instance not served behind load balancer in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am having a hard time troubleshooting why a static page hosted on an EC2 instance is not served through a load balancer.

I am certain the EC2 instance is configured correctly because:
- I can ping the instance when inbound ICMP is allowed in the associated security group
- I can browse the web page when I add the public name of the instance to the Outputs section (though I do not want to do this directly, as the instance is supposed to sit behind the load balancer).

So I think there is an issue with the security groups and/or the network routes.

Here is a simplified version of the CloudFormation template (supposed to be launched in `eu-west-1`):

[image]

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      InstanceTenancy: default
      EnableDnsSupport: 'true'
      EnableDnsHostnames: 'true'

  IGW:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::InternetGateway'

  IGWAttachment:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref IGW

  PublicSubnet:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1a
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: 'True'
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  App:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      DisableApiTermination: 'false'
      InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: stop
      ImageId: ami-70edb016
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      Monitoring: 'false'
      UserData: >-
        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
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'true'
          DeleteOnTermination: 'true'
          Description: Primary network interface
          DeviceIndex: 0
          SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet
          GroupSet:
            - !Ref SGApp

  ELB:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer'
    Properties:
      Subnets:
        - !Ref PublicSubnet
      Instances:
        - !Ref App
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref SGELB
      Listeners:
        - LoadBalancerPort: '80'
          InstancePort: '80'
          Protocol: HTTP
      HealthCheck:
        Target: 'HTTP:80/'
        HealthyThreshold: '3'
        UnhealthyThreshold: '5'
        Interval: '15'
        Timeout: '5'

  SGELB:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  AllowInboundHTTPToELB:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress'
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref SGELB
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: '80'
      ToPort: '80'
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  SGApp:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  AllowInboundHTTPFromELB:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress'
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref SGApp
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: '80'
      ToPort: '80'
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref SGELB
  RouteTable:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  PublicRoute:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      GatewayId: !Ref IGW

  SubnetRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet

Outputs:
  LoadBalancerDNSName:
    Value: !GetAtt ELB.DNSName
```

Comment: Once your CF template has created the resources go and check that the EC2 instance is in a healthy state in the ELB under the loadbalancers console. If it is unhealthy it will not route traffic to it.

Comment: The instance indeed shows as OutOfService. The health check is configured to run on HTTP:80/. Anything wrong with that? The instance itself shows up as Running on its own console.

Comment: Are the health check requests from the ELB actually making it to your web server (do you see the requests in the web server logs)?

Comment: I just changed the Health Check to TCP:80 and the instance shows up as InService now. So I think the problem is not with the instance, but rather my network settings. Could anyone take a look at the security groups, the ingress/egress rules and the network routes?

Comment: @jarmod: Setting the health check to HTTP:80/index.html also works. No idea why "/" does not work though...

Comment: @GeorgeRushby: would you mind converting your comment to an answer, so I can mark it as Accepted? Checking the health state was the right option indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your CF template has created the resources go and check that the EC2 instance is in a healthy state in the ELB under the loadbalancers console. If it is unhealthy it will not route traffic to it.

Answer (score 1):

I decrypted your `UserData` and could see you don't have an index.html, `HTTP:80/` will look for index.html by default. Since there is no index.html `httpd` would redirect to a test page with an `unhealthy` 302 response code, as you mentioned in the comments TCP:80 would work or use `HTTP:80/demo.html`

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd24
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on
groupadd www
usermod -a -G www ec2-user
chown -R root:www /var/www
chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +
echo '<html><head><title>Success!</title></head><body>Success!</body></html>' > /var/www/html/demo.html
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for clarifying the "/" issue I was having, and apologies for not including the decoded version in my original post. I wanted to keep things as simple and concise as possible, and I thought the instance was correctly configured.

Comment: No offense but I would rather wait for @GeorgeRushby to convert his comment to an answer, so I can accept it (as commented above). You really helped me understand the issue with the health check but George pointed me to the health check in the first place. Anyway, I will accept your answer if I do not hear from George soon.

Comment: Thanks @LaurentVaylet